# Is there a biome that has a higher chance to spawn Zombie Testificates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a survival map where no villages were spawned in (No idea why?) and I am in search of 2 zombie testificates so I can start my own village...
Are there any biomes where zombie testificates are more likely to spawn in?

Answer (score 1):

No matter where you are, whenever a zombie spawns there's a 5% chance of it being a zombie villager

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 biomes that have different spawn rates:

1) Mushroom Islands don't spawn hostile mobs.

2) Slimes spawn in swamps.

Neither of these boost the zombie villager spawn rate. The best way to get zombie villagers is to go outside and find zombies, or build a farm around a zombie spawner.

Answer (score 0):

To find zombie villagers go outside at night and am sure as long as zombies spawn there you'll have some zombie villagers because I think zombies have a chance of being zombie villagers (atleast that what happens for me all the time)

If u want villagers  just look for zombiie villagers and weaken it with a splash potion of weakness (if u have a brewing stand) and feed it a golden apple then you can have as many villagers as u can

Comment: As far as biomes, is there any more likely to spawn zombie testificates? The reason I ask is around the Mycelium Peninsula I'm living on (it's connected to a oak, birch, and spruce forest biome) I have not found any as of yet.